# PHP function for concating matching index strings in array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, concatenation

Alright, I know it can be done like so...

```
$Array1 = array("Hello, ", "foo", "The quick brown fox jumped ");
$Array2 = array("World!", "bar", "the lazy dog.");
$Array3 = array();
for($x = 0; $x < count($Array1); $x++) {
    $Array3[] = $Array1[$x] . $Array2[$x];
}
// returns this -> ("Hello, World", "foobar", "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.")
```

But is there a native PHP function for this? Like this:

```
$Array3 = array_concat_strings($Array1, $Array2)
```

I searched through php.net, and didn't find anything, but I like to be sure I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's such a particular native function, but you can make your own:

```
$array3 = array_map(function ($a, $b) { return $a . $b; }, $array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Ooh. Tidy. I may have to use this.

Comment: Requires PHP 5.3+, BTW. The syntax for 5.2- would require `create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a . $b;')`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there's no such a function

Answer (score 0):

There is no such native function, but you can do it without the third array, for example

```
foreach($Array1 as $key=>$value)
  $Array1[$key] .= $Array2[$key];

print_r($Array1);
```

Comment: In some instances where I have used this, I need all 3 arrays.
But, yeah, granted.

Comment: @Yoshiyahu so, copy one of the array and modify it that way :)